# how to save data in one HTML page and then display on another HTML page in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

My app requires users to save a map that they create, and then have it available for viewing later. How would this be done in a phonegap app which has different HTML pages? Would a new HTML page be required to view each different map, or would it share a similar HTML page that displays different data depending on the one that the user wishes to view?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. You can achieve the same results with several methods.

You can dynamically add the content in a single HTML page or you can forward it to a new one.

You can store your data using localStorage or in memory DB or using a dedicated DB solution or you can use phonegap's API http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to write your hybrid app as a Single Page Application (SPA) which is the best practice recommendation for PhoneGap/Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/next/index.html. This way you never actually leave the HTML page, but just give the impression by swapping in and out parts of your DOM.